# Creating a table with values of a subquery in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello my dear and faithful 'stackers'! I have following array:

```
$array = array(
    "0" => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
    "1" => array("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V"),
    "2" => array("i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v"),
    "3" => array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    ...,
    "9" => array("a", "b", "c", "d", "f"),
);
```

and would like to create a table with the values of the subarrays just like that:

```
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| i | ii | iii | iv | v |
| A | B  |  C  | D  | E |
|...|    |     |    |   |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
```

I tried so:

```
$table = '<table border=1>';
// Select values of the array to create table.
foreach($array as $row){
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        $table .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row['0'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['1'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['2'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['3'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['4'].'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
}
$table .= '</table>';
```

but the problem is that every subarray is displayed 8 times in the table...

```
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| 1 | 2  |  3  | 4  | 5 |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
| I | II | III | IV | V |
|...|    |     |    |   |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
| a | b  |  c  | d  | e |
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would apreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

== UPDATE ==

After some kind tips from Félix Gagnon-Grenier the code must be:

```
<?php

$array = array(
"0" => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
"1" => array("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V"),
"2" => array("i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v"),
"3" => array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
"9" => array("a", "b", "c", "d", "f")
);

print_r($array);


$table = '<table border=1>';
// Select values of the array to create table.
foreach($array as $key => $row){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $value){
        $table .= '
                <td>'.$value.'</td>
        ';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
?>
```

So it works fine!

Comment: You're talking about while, or for each loops:http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you almost got it

```
foreach($array as $key => $row){
    $table.= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $value){
        $table.= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    $table.= '</tr>';
}
```

you want a new table row for each initial array, then a new table cell for each value

Comment: it's for concatenation of strings in php http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Dear @félix-gagnon-grenier it worked, but not fully. Now I have the results of each subarray 5 times in one line:

     1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 etc.
     A | B | C | D | E | A | B | C | D | E etc.
     a | b | c | d | e | a | b | c | d | e etc.

And I think it repeats 5 times because we have 5 values in each subarray...

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil please update your question and add the new code you are using. Are you doing it exactly like I wrote?

Comment: @Aloysia de Argenteuil It's the basic output, you need to put a little HTML into the loop in order to break it apart some.

Comment: Dear @FélixGagnon-Grenier thank you for your help. I've just updated the question with the new code.

Comment: Dear @FélixGagnon-Grenier, it works... It was my bad. I didn't delete the <td>'.$row['0'].'</td> part. Now it's Ok Thank you so much!!!

Comment: And if I would like to exclude some of the values of the subarray to create the table? We say the second value of each line just like:  1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | A | C | D | E  etc.
Would it be possible?

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil I'm very sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you mean... but feel free to update your question with this new one or even ask a new question with this specific problem, along with what you have attempted to solve it

Comment: Dear @FélixGagnon-Grenier thank you for your help. I asked a new question as you said. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24619181/3499881 . I've received some answers already, but maybe you have a very good answer as you did in this post. Thanks!