# How to change order of subarray values to create a table using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have following code that creates a table from the values of the subarrays as discussed here: [Creating a table with values of a subquery in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24613777/3499881)

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "0" => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
    "1" => array("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V"),
    "2" => array("i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v"),
    "3" => array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    "9" => array("a", "b", "c", "d", "f")
);

print_r($array);

    $table = '<table border=1>';
    // Select values of the array to create table.
    foreach($array as $key => $row){
        $table .= '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value){
            $table .= '
                    <td>'.$value.'</td>
            ';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';

    echo $table;
?>
```

The table is like:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
...
| A | B | C | D | E |
| a | b | c | d | e |
etc.
```

But what could I do, if I like to exclude some values and have others in another order just like the following?

```
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 2 |
| C | D | E | B |
| c | d | e | b |
etc.
```

In another words what I have to do to exclude the first value and put the second in the last cell of the table?

Comment: Will the array always contain a "2" that you ALWAYs want at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a seperate array to keep track of which column to show, and keep that array in the order you want.

```
$array = array(
  "0" => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
  "1" => array("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V"),
  "2" => array("i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v"),
  "3" => array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  "9" => array("a", "b", "c", "d", "f")
);
$column_order = array(2,3,4,1);
//indexes are 0 based, so column "2" is going to be "C" for example
$table = '<table border=1>';
// Select values of the array to create table.
foreach($array as $key => $row){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($column_order as $index){
        $table .= '
                <td>'.(array_key_exists($index, $row) ? $row[$index] : '').'</td>
        ';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to preface this by saying there is not a good way to do what you are asking.  You SHOULD create an index order and follow it.

Ignoring a column is easy, simply check if the key is to be ignored...

Moving a column to the end, would be better achieved by swapping subarrays, but can be done through some abuse of your iterations.

```
$table = '<table border=1>';
// Select values of the array to create table.
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($j = 0; $j < count($array[$i]) + 1; $j++)
    {            
        if($j > 1) // Skip first and second columns
             $table .= '
                    <td>'.$array[$i][$j].'</td>
            ';
        else if($j == count($array[$i]))  //if past the alst column
             $table .= '
                    <td>'.$array[$i][1].'</td> //Use Second column
            ';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
```